# Appearance of an angle of inclination on a horizontal rod moving upwards after a Lorentz Transformation

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames

If i have in one inertial reference frame called $S':(x',y',z',t')$ a rod with lenght $l$ in the plane $z'=0$ and parallel with the $x'$ axis, moving with a velocity $u$ in the direction of the $y'$ axis, so i think therefore that the extreme points of the rod can be given in $S'$ by 
$$P'_1:(x'_1 , y'_1 , z'_1 , t'_1) = (x'_1 , ut'_1 ,z'_1 , t'_1) $$
$$P'_2:(x'_2 , y'_2 , z'_2 , t'_2) =(x'_1 + l , ut'_1 , z'_1 , t'_1)$$

Given that there is a inertial reference frame $S:(x,y,z,t)$ ; in relation to which the reference frame $S'$ is moving with velocity $v$ in the $x$ direction, and such that in the time $t=0$ both reference frames coincided, and after that, the $z'$ axis continued parallel to the $z$ axis as did the $y'$ axis parallel to $y$ axis and the $x'$ axis continued in the same direction as the $x$ axis.

So to get the points $P'_1$ and $P'_2$ in the frame $S$ i tried to do the lorentz inverse transform in each point as it is shown bellow:

\begin{equation}
P'_1 \Rightarrow P_{1}
    \begin{cases}
      x_1=\gamma (x'_1+vt'_1) \\
      y_1 = y'_1 =ut'_1\\
      z_1 = z'_1\\
      t_1 = \gamma(t'_1+\frac{v}{c^2}x'_1)
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
P'_2 \Rightarrow P_{2}
    \begin{cases}
      x_2=\gamma ((x'_1+l)+vt'_2) = \gamma ((x'_1+l)+vt'_1)\\
      y_2 = y'_2 =ut'_2=ut'_1\\
      z_2 = z'_2 = z'_1\\
      t_2 = \gamma(t'_2+\frac{v}{c^2}(x'_1+l)) = \gamma(t'_1+\frac{v}{c^2}(x'_1+l))
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

But then if $t'_2 = t'_1$  there would be no $y$ axis inclination as the problem sugests, what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: But it says that for homework type of problems, as long as it is targeted at a specific conceptual physics question it is alright to ask, and in this post targets the conceptual problem of how do angles transform under Lorentz transformations, in a given occurrence.  If you had read it is not a "check my work" type of question because i actually didn't come to any conclusion, i just have laid the foundations of how i think the problem should have been solved, and came to a conclusion that contradicts what was expected demonstrating a misunderstanding of the method of solution.

Comment: Take a look in my answer herein :[General matrix Lorentz transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/361227/general-matrix-lorentz-transformation/361317#361317). May be answers your question too.

Comment: @FelipeDilho You're right that it's fine to ask about some physics concept that happens to be involved in the problem you're solving. But I don't see that here. All I see you asking is "what am I doing wrong?" That being said, I think there may be a way to make this question fine for the site with a small edit. I'll think about what that might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :** We have here 3 frames and 2 Lorentz Transformations. (1) Frame $\:\mathrm S\left(x,y,z\right)\:$ (2) frame $\:\mathrm S'\left(x',y',z'\right)\:$ moving with respect to $\:\mathrm S\left(x,y,z\right)\:$ with velocity $\:\mathbf{v}=\left(v,0,0\right)\:$ along the common $\:x-,x'-$axis (3) frame $\:\mathrm S''\left(x'',y'',z''\right)\:$, the rest frame of the rod, moving with respect to $\:\mathrm S'\left(x',y',z'\right)\:$ with velocity $\:\mathbf{u}=\left(0,u,0\right)\:$ along the common $\:y'-,y''-$axis.

I suggest to take a look in my answer therein : [General matrix Lorentz transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/361227/general-matrix-lorentz-transformation/361317#361317)

---

**EDIT**

We have here two 2+1-Lorentz transformations. So the axes $\:z,z',z''\:$ are ignored.

[image]

From Figure 01 :

Lorentz Transformation from $\:\mathrm{S}\equiv \{xy\eta, \eta=ct\}\:$ to $\:\mathrm{S'}\equiv \{x'y'\eta', \eta'=ct'\}\:$
\begin{equation}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     x'\\
     y'\\
     \eta'
   \end{bmatrix}
   =
   \begin{bmatrix}
     \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta & 0 & \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\zeta \\
     0 & 1 & 0 \\
      \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\zeta & 0 & \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta \\
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     x\\
     y\\
     \eta
   \end{bmatrix}
   \,, \quad \tanh\zeta=\dfrac{v}{c}
\tag{01}   
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
   \mathbf{X'}=\mathrm{L'}\mathbf{X}\,, \qquad \mathrm{L'}=
   \begin{bmatrix}
     \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta & 0 & \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\zeta \\
     0 & 1 & 0 \\
      \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\zeta & 0 & \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta \\
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{01"}   
\end{equation}

[image]

From Figure 02:

Lorentz Transformation from $\:\mathrm{S'}\equiv \{x'y'\eta', \eta'=ct'\}\:$ to $\:\mathrm{S''}\equiv \{x''y''\eta'', \eta''=ct''\}\:$
\begin{equation}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     x''\\
     y''\\
     \eta''
   \end{bmatrix}
   =
   \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 &\hphantom{-}\cosh\xi &  \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\xi \\
     0 & \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\xi &  \hphantom{-}\cosh\xi \\
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
     x'\\
     y'\\
     \eta'
   \end{bmatrix}
   \,, \quad \tanh\xi=\dfrac{u}{c}
\tag{02}   
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
   \mathbf{X''}=\mathrm{L''}\mathbf{X'}\,, \qquad \mathrm{L''}=
   \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 &\hphantom{-}\cosh\xi &  \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\xi \\
     0 & \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\xi &  \hphantom{-}\cosh\xi \\
   \end{bmatrix}  
\tag{02"}   
\end{equation}
Note that because of the Standard Configurations the matrices $\:\mathrm{L'}, \mathrm{L''}\:$ are real symmetric.

From equations (01) and (02) we have
\begin{equation}   \mathbf{X''}=\mathrm{L''}\mathbf{X'}=\mathrm{L''}\mathrm{L'}\mathbf{X}\Longrightarrow \mathbf{X''}=\Lambda\mathbf{X} 
\tag{03}   
\end{equation}
where $\:\Lambda\:$ the composition of the two Lorentz Transformations $\:\mathrm{L'}, \mathrm{L''}\:$
\begin{equation}
\Lambda=\mathrm{L''}\mathrm{L'}=
\begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 &\hphantom{-}\cosh\xi &  \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\xi \\
     0 & \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\xi &  \hphantom{-}\cosh\xi \\
   \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
     \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta & 0 & \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\zeta \\
     0 & 1 & 0 \\
      \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\zeta & 0 & \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta \\
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{04}   
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
\Lambda=
  \begin{bmatrix}
     \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta & 0 & \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\zeta \\
     \hphantom{-}\sinh\zeta\sinh\xi   &\hphantom{-}\cosh\xi &  \boldsymbol{-}\cosh\zeta\sinh\xi \\
     \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\zeta\cosh\xi & \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\xi &  \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta\cosh\xi \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\tag{04"}   
\end{equation}

In the following it's necessary to have the inverse transformation $\:\Lambda^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\:$ which could be determined from :
\begin{equation}
\Lambda^{\boldsymbol{-}1}=\mathrm{L\!'}^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\mathrm{L\!''}^{\boldsymbol{-}1}
\tag{05}   
\end{equation}
For the  inverse transformations $\:\mathrm{L\!'}^{\boldsymbol{-}1},\mathrm{L\!''}^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\:$ we have respectively
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{L'}\left(\zeta\right)=
   \begin{bmatrix}
     \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta & 0 & \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\zeta \\
     0 & 1 & 0 \\
     \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\zeta & 0 & \hphantom{-}\cosh\zeta \\
   \end{bmatrix}
 \Longrightarrow  
\mathrm{L\!'}^{\boldsymbol{-}1}=\mathrm{L'}\left(\boldsymbol{-}\zeta\right)=
\begin{bmatrix}
     \cosh\zeta & 0 & \sinh\zeta \\
     0 & 1 & 0 \\
      \sinh\zeta & 0 & \cosh\zeta \\
   \end{bmatrix}
\tag{06}   
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{L''}\left(\xi\right)=
   \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 &\hphantom{-}\cosh\xi &  \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\xi \\
     0 & \boldsymbol{-}\sinh\xi &  \hphantom{-}\cosh\xi \\
   \end{bmatrix} 
 \Longrightarrow  
\mathrm{L\!''}^{\boldsymbol{-}1}=\mathrm{L''}\left(\boldsymbol{-}\xi\right)=
   \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 &\cosh\xi &  \sinh\xi \\
     0 & \sinh\xi & \cosh\xi \\
   \end{bmatrix} 
\tag{07}   
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\!\!\!\!\!\!
\Lambda^{\boldsymbol{-}1} \!=\!
    \begin{bmatrix}
     \cosh\zeta & 0 & \sinh\zeta \\
     0 & 1 & 0 \\
      \sinh\zeta & 0 & \cosh\zeta \\
   \end{bmatrix}
   \!\!\!
   \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 &\cosh\xi &  \sinh\xi \\
     0 & \sinh\xi & \cosh\xi \\
   \end{bmatrix}
   \!=\!
   \begin{bmatrix}
     \cosh\zeta & \sinh\zeta\sinh\xi & \sinh\zeta\cosh\xi \\
     0   &\hphantom{-}\cosh\xi &  \sinh\xi \\
      \sinh\zeta & \cosh\zeta\sinh\xi & \cosh\zeta\cosh\xi \\
  \end{bmatrix}\!\!\!\!
\tag{08}   
\end{equation}

We need also the velocity vector, let $\:\mathbf{w}$, of the translational motion of the frame $\:\mathrm S''\left(x'',y''\right)\:$ with respect to the frame $\:\mathrm S\left(x,y\right)$. This vector is the relativistic sum of two orthogonal velocity vectors $\:\mathbf{v}=\left(\upsilon\,,0\right),\mathbf{u}=\left(0\,,u\right)$<sup>(1)</sup>
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{v}+\dfrac{\mathbf{u}}{\gamma_{\upsilon}}=\left[\upsilon\,,\left(\!1\!-\!\frac{\upsilon^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)^{\!\!\frac12}\!\!u\right]\,,\quad \gamma_{\upsilon}  = \left(\!1\!-\!\frac{\upsilon^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)^{\!\!\boldsymbol{-}\frac12}=\cosh\zeta
\tag{09}   
\end{equation}
not to be confused with the relativistic sum of two collinear velocity vectors pointing to the same direction
\begin{equation}
w \ne \dfrac{\upsilon\!+\!u}{1+\dfrac{\upsilon u}{c^{2}}}
\tag{10}   
\end{equation}
From (09) we have
\begin{align}
\dfrac{w_{x}}{c} & = \dfrac{\upsilon}{\:\:c\:\:}=\tanh\zeta
\tag{11.1}\\
\dfrac{w_{y}}{c} & = \dfrac{u}{\gamma_{\upsilon}c}= \dfrac{\tanh\xi}{\cosh\zeta}
\tag{11.2}\\
\left(\dfrac{w}{c}\right)^{2}  & = \left(\dfrac{w_{x}}{c}\right)^{2}+\left(\dfrac{w_{y}}{c}\right)^{2}=1-\left(\dfrac{1}{\cosh\zeta\cosh\xi}\right)^{2}=\dfrac{\gamma^{2}_{w}\!-\!1}{\gamma^{2}_{w}}
\tag{11.3}\\
\gamma_{w}  & = \left(\!1\!-\!\frac{w^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)^{\boldsymbol{-}\frac12}=\cosh\zeta\cosh\xi=\gamma_{\upsilon}\gamma_{u}
\tag{11.4}
\end{align}

Now, let a rod of length $\:\boldsymbol{\ell}\:$ at rest in frame $\:\mathrm S''\:$ parallel to the $\:x''\!\!-$axis, see Figure 03. The end points of the rod are observed in $\:\mathrm S''\:$ simultaneously at a given time moment $\:t''\!\!-$ so we have two events $\:\mathrm 1''\:$ and $\:\mathrm 2''\:$ separated by the space-time vector
\begin{equation}
\Delta\mathbf{X''}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \Delta x''\\
    \Delta y''\\
    \Delta \eta''
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x''_{2}-x''_{1}\\
    y''_{2}-y''_{1}\\
    c\left(t''_{2}-t''_{1}\right)
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \boldsymbol{\ell}\\
    0\\
    0
  \end{bmatrix}
  \tag{12}   
\end{equation}

[image]

In frame $\:\mathrm S\:$ the two events are observed as two events $\:\mathrm 1\:$ and $\:\mathrm 2\:$ separated by the space-time vector
\begin{equation}
\Delta\mathbf{X}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \Delta x\\
    \Delta y\\
    \Delta \eta
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{2}-x_{1}\\
    y_{2}-y_{1}\\
    c\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right)
  \end{bmatrix}
  \tag{13}   
\end{equation}
which is connected with $\:\Delta\mathbf{X''}\:$ by the  $\:\Lambda^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\:$ transformation
\begin{equation}
\Delta\mathbf{X}=\Lambda^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\Delta\mathbf{X''}
\tag{14}   
\end{equation}
From equations (08) and (12) we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \Delta x\\
    \Delta y\\
    \Delta \eta
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
     \cosh\zeta & \sinh\zeta\sinh\xi & \sinh\zeta\cosh\xi \\
     0   &\hphantom{-}\cosh\xi &  \sinh\xi \\
      \sinh\zeta & \cosh\zeta\sinh\xi & \cosh\zeta\cosh\xi
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \boldsymbol{\ell}\\
     0\\
     0
  \end{bmatrix}
\tag{15}   
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\Delta x=\boldsymbol{\ell} \cosh\zeta \,, \quad \Delta y=0\,, \quad \Delta \eta= c\Delta t=\boldsymbol{\ell}\sinh\zeta 
\tag{16}   
\end{equation}

[image]

Equation (16) is represented in Figure 04. But this view is not a snapshot of the rod at a given time moment $\:t\:$ in $\:\mathrm S\left(x,y\right)$. To the contrary, it's a montage of snapshots of the points along the rod, each point shown at its own time moment. So, the end $\:\mathrm 1\:$ of the rod is shown on its position at the time moment $\:t_{1}\:$, the end $\:\mathrm 2\:$ of the rod is shown on its position at the time moment $\:t_{2}\:$ and an intermediate point $\:\mathrm 3\:$ with coordinate $\:x_{3}\in \left[x_{1},x_{2}\right]\:$ at the time moment $\:t_{3}\:$
\begin{equation}
t_{3}=t_{1}+\dfrac{x_{3}-x_{1}}{x_{2}-x_{1}}\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right)
\tag{17}   
\end{equation}
To observe the rod at a given time moment $\:t\:$ in $\:\mathrm S\left(x,y\right)$, for example at $\:t_{1}\:$, we must return the end point $\:\mathrm 2\:$ from its position at time $\:t_{2}\:$ to its position at time $\:t_{1}\:$ since $\:\mathrm 1\:$ is already shown at time $\:t_{1}$.

[image]

This is done in Figure 05. Since the rod is in translational motion with velocity vector $\:\mathbf{w}\:$ in frame $\:\mathrm S\left(x,y\right)$, the two positions of $\:\mathrm 2\:$ at time moments $\:t_{1},t_{2}$ are separated by the vector $\:\mathbf{w}\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right)$ and from  equations (11.1),(11.2),(16) we have
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{w}\Delta t=\!\dfrac{\mathbf{w}}{c}\Delta \eta\!=\left(\dfrac{w_{x}}{c},\dfrac{w_{y}}{c}\right)\boldsymbol{\ell}\sinh\!\zeta=   \left(\tanh\!\zeta,\dfrac{  \tanh\!\xi}{\cosh\!\zeta}\right)\boldsymbol{\ell}\sinh\!\zeta
\tag{18}   
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{w}\Delta t= \left(\boldsymbol{\ell}\sinh\!\zeta\tanh\!\zeta,\boldsymbol{\ell}\tanh\!\zeta\tanh\!\xi\right)
\tag{19}   
\end{equation}
From details in Figure 05 about the lengths of line segments
\begin{equation}
\tan\!\theta=\dfrac{\boldsymbol{\ell}\!\tanh\!\zeta\!\tanh\!\xi}{\dfrac{\boldsymbol{\ell}}{\cosh\!\zeta}}=\sinh\!\zeta\tanh\!\xi
\tag{20}   
\end{equation}
but
\begin{equation}
\sinh\!\zeta=\underbrace{\cosh\!\zeta}_{\gamma_{\upsilon}}\underbrace{\tanh\!\zeta}_{\upsilon/c}=\dfrac{\gamma_{\upsilon}\upsilon}{c}\,, \quad \tanh\!\xi=\dfrac{u}{c}
\tag{21}   
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\tan\!\theta=\dfrac{\gamma_{\upsilon}\upsilon u}{c^{2}}=\left(1-\dfrac{\upsilon^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)^{\boldsymbol{-}\frac12}\dfrac{\upsilon u}{c^{2}}\:}
\tag{22}   
\end{equation}
For the length $\:\boldsymbol{\ell}_{\mathrm S}\:$ of the inclined rod in frame $\: \mathrm S\:$ we have from the orthogonal triangle in Figure 05
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\ell}_{\mathrm S}^{2}=\left(\dfrac{\boldsymbol{\ell}}{\cosh\!\zeta}\right)^{\!\!2}+\left(\boldsymbol{\ell}\!\tanh\!\zeta\!\tanh\!\xi\vphantom{\dfrac12}\right)^{\!\!2}=\left[1 -\dfrac{\upsilon^{2}}{c^{2}}\left(1-\dfrac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)\right]\boldsymbol{\ell}^{2}
\tag{23} 
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\boldsymbol{\ell}_{\mathrm S}=\sqrt{1 -\dfrac{\upsilon^{2}}{c^{2}}\left(1-\dfrac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)}\:\boldsymbol{\ell}\:}
\tag{24}   
\end{equation}

From (22) and (24) we have verifications of the following two special cases :

1. If $\:\color{blue}{u=0}\:$ then $\:\theta\!=\! 0\:$, the rod is moving parallel to the $\:x-$axis with speed $\:\upsilon\:$ , contracted from $\:\boldsymbol{\ell}\:$ to $\:\boldsymbol{\ell}/\cosh\!\zeta$.
2. If $\:\color{blue}{\upsilon\!=\! 0}\:$ then $\:\theta\!=\! 0\:$, the rod is parallel to the $\:x-$axis with unchanged length $\:\boldsymbol{\ell}$ moving in the direction of the $\:y-$axis with speed $\:u$.

---

Numerical Examples :
\begin{equation}
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    \upsilon/c=0.60\\
    u/c=0.40
  \end{Bmatrix}
\quad =\!=\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow\quad 
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    \tan\!\theta=0.30 \\
    \theta=16.70^{\,\rm o} \\
    \boldsymbol{\ell}_{\mathrm S}=0.835\, \boldsymbol{\ell}
  \end{Bmatrix}
\tag{25}   
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    \upsilon/c=0.80\\
    u/c=0.60
  \end{Bmatrix}
\quad =\!=\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow\quad 
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    \tan\!\theta=0.80 \\
    \theta=38.66^{\,\rm o} \\
    \boldsymbol{\ell}_{\mathrm S}=0.768\, \boldsymbol{\ell}
  \end{Bmatrix}
\tag{26}   
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    \upsilon/c\:\longrightarrow\:1\\
    u/c\:\longrightarrow\:1
  \end{Bmatrix}
\quad =\!=\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow\quad 
  \begin{Bmatrix}
    \tan\!\theta\:\longrightarrow\:+\infty \\
    \hphantom{\:\tan\theta}\theta\:\longrightarrow\:90.00^{\,\rm o} \\
    \boldsymbol{\ell}_{\mathrm S}\:\longrightarrow\:\boldsymbol{\ell}
  \end{Bmatrix}
  \text{!!!!!!}
\tag{27}   
\end{equation}

---

<sup>(1)
We can derive equations (11.1),(11.2) for the components of the velocity vector $\:\mathbf{w}\:$ using the Lorentz transformation $\:\mathrm{L\!'}^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\:$ between frames $\:\mathrm S',\mathrm S\:$ instead of equation (09)(the last is given without proof and comes from on a general 3+1-Lorentz Transformation)</sup>

<sup>So, suppose that the origin $\:\mathrm O''\:$ of frame $\:\mathrm S''\:$  is a particle moving in frame $\:\mathrm S'\:$ with velocity vector    
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{u}=\left(\dfrac{\mathrm d x'}{\mathrm d t'},\dfrac{\mathrm d y'}{\mathrm d t'}\right)=\left(0,u\right)
\tag{ft-01}   
\end{equation}
From equation (06) for the Lorentz transformation $\:\mathrm{L\!'}^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\:$ \begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathrm d x\\
    \mathrm d y\\
    \mathrm d\eta
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
     \cosh\zeta & 0 & \sinh\zeta \\
     0 & 1 & 0 \\
      \sinh\zeta & 0 & \cosh\zeta \\
   \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathrm d x'\\
    \mathrm d y'\\
    \mathrm d\eta'
  \end{bmatrix}
\tag{ft-02}   
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
  \mathrm dx & =\cosh\!\zeta \,\mathrm d x'+\sinh\!\zeta \,\mathrm d\eta'
  \tag{ft-03a}\\
  \mathrm dy & =\mathrm dy'
  \tag{ft-03b}\\
  \mathrm d\eta  & = \sinh\!\zeta \,\mathrm dx'+\cosh\!\zeta \,\mathrm d\eta'
  \tag{ft-03c}
\end{align}
dividing (ft-03a) and (ft-03b) by (ft-03c) 
\begin{align}
  \dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm d\eta} & =\dfrac{\cosh\!\zeta \,\mathrm d x'+\sinh\!\zeta \,\mathrm d\eta'}{\sinh\!\zeta \,\mathrm dx'+\cosh\!\zeta \,\mathrm d\eta'}=\dfrac{\cosh\!\zeta \, \left(\dfrac{\mathrm dx'}{\mathrm d\eta'}\right)+\sinh\!\zeta}{\sinh\!\zeta \, \left(\dfrac{\mathrm dx'}{\mathrm d\eta'}\right)+\cosh\!\zeta}
  \tag{ft-04a}\\
  \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm d\eta} & =\dfrac{\mathrm dy'}{\sinh\!\zeta \,\mathrm dx'+\cosh\!\zeta \,\mathrm d\eta'}=\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{\mathrm dy'}{\mathrm d\eta'}\right)}{\sinh\!\zeta \, \left(\dfrac{\mathrm dx'}{\mathrm d\eta'}\right)+\cosh\!\zeta}
  \tag{ft-04b}
\end{align}
From (ft-01) having in mind that  $\eta=ct,\eta'=ct'$
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mathrm dx'}{\mathrm d\eta'}=0\,,\qquad \dfrac{\mathrm dy'}{\mathrm d\eta'}=\dfrac{u}{c}=\tanh\!\xi
\tag{ft-05}   
\end{equation}
Inserting expressions (ft-05) in (ft-04a,b) we have finally
\begin{align}
\dfrac{w_{x}}{c} & =\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm d\eta} =\tanh\zeta=\dfrac{\upsilon}{\:\:c\:\:}
\tag{11.1}\\
\dfrac{w_{y}}{c} & = \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm d\eta}=\dfrac{\tanh\xi}{\cosh\zeta}=\dfrac{u}{\gamma_{\upsilon}c}
\tag{11.2}
\end{align}</sup>

---

------[Figure 06 : The Length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSy45.png)------
[Figure 07 : The Angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viIKE.png)------